# Create an array of size n with initialized value

Tags: python, arrays

In python, it's possible to create an array of size n with `[] * n` or even initialize a fixed value for all items with `[0] * n`.

Is it possible to do something similar but initialize the value with `500n`?

For example, create an array with size of 10 would result in this.

`[0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500]`

I can easily achieve this with a variable and a for loop as shown below but I would like optimize this in one go to pass into Robot Framework.

```py
arr = [0] * 10
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
  arr[i] = 500 * i
```

Comment: `len([] * n) == 0`, and those are *lists*. But why not `list(range(0, 500 * n, 500))`? Or `[500 * index for index in range(n)]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a simple comprehension:

```
[i*500 for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer gives you a way, here's another :

```py
list(range(0, 500*n, 500))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's allways a good idea to use numpy arrays. They have more fuctionalites and are very fast in use (vectorized form, and fast compiled C-code under the hood). Your example with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

nx = 10
a = 500*np.arange(nx)
a
```

gives:

```
array([   0,  500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500])
```